# Correct selection of flags for extension

Tags: api-design, naming

In my library (DLL), I have extensions for List like the next one.

```
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Sub Store(Of TVal As IFullyOperable)(items As List(Of TVal), w As BinaryWriter, closeAfter As Boolean)
    Try
        w.Write7BitEncodedInt(items.Count)
        items.ForEach(Sub(i) i.Store(w))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    Finally
        If closeAfter Then w.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

`IFullyOperable` - a public interface that must be implemented in classes to make them suitable for processing by my library.

For now, I have a flag `closeAfter` in most calls `False`, but I doubt, maybe it better to use `leaveOpen` like in the constructor of `BinaryWriter` from dotNet?

Using of `leaveOpen` will cause redundant inversions, but make code more look like part of dotNet, and can improve usability, or not?

What are the considerations about using both of these variants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For variants like the one you mention, the most important consideration is the cognitive load that each option brings with it. That is the cognitive load for both the maintainers of the function **and** the cognitive load for the users of the function.

You need to find a balancing point between how easy it is to accidentally interpret the parameter in the wrong way when reading or making changes to the functions, versus how easy it is to accidentally pass the wrong value to the parameter when calling the function.

If there is an established pattern within the .Net ecosystem to have a parameter with the semantics of `leaveOpen`, then that on its own is already a good argument to follow that same pattern, as it will cause less confusion for your users. If the effect on your code is also only a simple `not`, then the effect on the cognitive load for your users far outweighs the cognitive load for your maintainers.

Comment: Ok, considering your answer I decide to use the leaveOpen-pattern to achieve unification with .Net.